# get list class and change it into any language by Unicode

Tags: html, css, html-lists

hi i've made a list in html:

```html
<ul id="queNans">
<li class="que">put letter 'क' instead bullets</li>
<li class="ans">put arrow like this '→' instead of bullets</li>
<li>how to do that?</li>
</ul>
```

so this is list in html with bulletes. i want to remove bullets of first list and put letter 'क' which unicode is '0915' and in second list i want to remove bullets and keep arrow like this '→' which unicode is '2192' by calling it in css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `:before` set `content:''`

```css
ul#queNans li{
  position:relative;
  list-style:none;
  line-height:100%;
  vertical-align:middle;
}

ul#queNans li.que:before{
  position:absolute;
  content:'\0915)';
  left:-20px;
  top:2px;
  font-size:14px;
}

ul#queNans li.ans:before{
  position:absolute;
  content:'\2192';
  left:-20px;
  top:2px;
  font-size:14px;
}
```

```html
<ul id="queansfirst">
<li>put letter 'क' instead bullets</li>
<li>put arrow like this '→' instead of bullets</li>
<li>how to do that?</li>
</ul>

<ul id="queNans">
<li class="que">put letter 'क' instead bullets</li>
<li class="ans">put arrow like this '→' instead of bullets</li>
<li>how to do that?</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: omg! thank you very much @HirenVaghasiya and if i want to apply these changes only to the list which is bound by certain div then how can i do that? coz is affecting all the lists in the html.

Comment: @Dibas add parent class of div to .class ul li

Comment: that worked but please also adjust this list as of others; i mean others list view and this is not inlined as equal; i removed paddings and made them look equal but could make them look parallel horizontally. please help me?

Comment: @Dibas parallel horizontally means how do you want it align?

Comment: i mean like this https://drive.google.com/file/d/19GizHmXO_q7JdJ-q7WQeu0t9xtS4o5-X/view?usp=sharing

Comment: it is not adjusting as of other list view; i tried but couldnot adjust; thanks for answering my silly questions though :)

Comment: @Dibas Updated as per my understanding of your align issue

Comment: one last last question please, please sir, actually i want to add "क)" like this no like this "क"; sorry sir; :); i tried to concatenate in content but it didnt worked

Comment: yes it worked :) but insted of bullet i actually want to add "क)" but we did only "क" how to add ")" in it  please sir :)

Comment: yes yes fixed that. thank you very much for your help sir; i didi this and it worked  "  content:'\0915\0028';" can we be friend in any social meadia or other sir? please?